# Remove socket form array work incorrectly

Tags: arrays, node.js, socket.io

When I rapidly refresh a browser then sometimes socket objects are not removed form the array, and if I leave it for a minute, it decreases to 5 or 6 but never back to 1 connection.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    users.push(socket);
    var my_index = users.indexOf(socket);
    console.log("Im number " + (my_index+1) + " form " + users.length);
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);

    initSocketData(socket);

    socket.on('client_data', function(data){
        for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
           users[i].emit('a_in', {'a_in': data});
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket){
        clearInterval(timer)
        if (my_index > -1) {
            users.splice(my_index, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

And the console output

```
$ node socket.js
Im number 1 form 1
Im number 1 form 1
Im number 1 form 1
Im number 1 form 1
Im number 2 form 2
Im number 3 form 3
Im number 4 form 4
Im number 5 form 5
Im number 6 form 6
Im number 6 form 6
Im number 7 form 7
Im number 8 form 8
Im number 9 form 9
Im number 9 form 9
Im number 10 form 10
Im number 11 form 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sync disconnect on unload` flag to tell the client do send a disconnect package on window close.

```
io.connect('http://adress/', {'sync disconnect on unload':true});
```

Comment: I put `var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8001/', {'sync disconnect on unload':true});` on html file but it still happen